# Itunes 64bits on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wine, playonlinux, itunes

How do I install itunes 64bits on Ubuntu 14.04 ? Using PlayOnLinux couldn't help me out to install the 64bit version of the latest itunes.

Comment: What happens exactly? We need more details in order to be able to help. Please [edit] your question and clarify how it doesn't work exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly the last version of iTunes that works trough Wine is the latest compatible with Windows XP which was 32bit. It can still be downloaded from the official Apple site at https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1614

It can be installed, music and video playback works well, and you can access the store too, however purchasing non free items and iOS sync does not work.

There is more information regarding installation and operation at WineHQ web site: https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=31322&iTestingId=91429